# Adding in basic variable command

Tags: shell, variable-substitution

Commands are..

```
t=20
s=$t+30
```

I want the output of `echo $s` to be `50`, but I cannot figure out how to write the `s=` command to get it to perform addition.

Comment: You could `man bash` (or your preferred shell) and read the section on arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Shell variables are strings by default. Some shells support other variable types, but you have to let the shell know.

In any POSIX-style shell (`sh` except on ancient Unix systems, dash, bash, ksh, zsh, etc.), you can use [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) to tell the shell to perform arithmetic when it's parsing the variable assignment.

```
t=20
s=$((t+30))
echo "$s"
```

(The double quotes are not necessary here, but [they're a good habit to pick up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).)

It's also possible to store the text of the expression to evaluate, and perform the arithmetic when printing it out.

```
t=20
s=$((t+30))
echo "expression: $s; evaluated: $(($s))"
```

But be careful with using explicit variable substitutions inside arithmetic expressions: they're substituted as text, not as arithmetic subexpressions, so operator precedence might look weird.

```
echo "$(($s*2))" # equivalent to $((t+30*2)), so prints 80, not 100
```

In bash, ksh or zsh, you can use [`let`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-let) or [`((…))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-select) to perform arithmetic instead.

```
t=20
let s=t+30
echo "$s"
```

or

```
((t = 20))
((s = t + 30))
echo "$s"
```

or variations thereof.

Another possibility in bash, ksh or zsh is to use the [`typeset`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-typeset) builtin to declare the variable as an integer. Then every assignment to it performs arithmetic evaluation.

```
typeset -i s t
t=20
s=t+30
echo "$s"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
t=20  

s=$((t+30))  # or s="$((t+30))"

echo "$s"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform arithmetic using the `expr` command, take e.g.:

```
t=20
s=$(expr "$t" + 30)
echo "$s"
```

type `man expr` on your terminal for more info.